# rvest vs RSelenium results for text extracting

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

So far i am using `RSelenium` to extract the text of a Homepage, but i would like to Switch to a fast solution like `rvest`.

```
library(rvest)
url = 'https://www.r-bloggers.com'
rvestResults <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_node('body') %>%
  html_text()

library(RSelenium)
remDr$navigate(url)
rSelResults <- remDr$findElement(
  using = "xpath",
  value = "//body"
)$getElementText()
```

Comparing the results below Shows that rvest includes some JavaScript Code, while
the RSelenium is much "cleaner".

I am aware of the differences between rvest and rselenium, that rselenium uses a headless browser and rvest just reads the "plain Homepage".

**My question would be: Is there a way i can get the Rselenium Output below with rvest or equally fast (or faster) as/than rvest with a third way?**

Rvest results:

```
> substring(rvestResults, 1, 500)
[1] "\n\n\n\t\t    \t    \t\n        \n        R news and tutorials contributed by (750) R bloggers         \n    Home\nAbout\nRSS\nadd your blog!\nLearn R\nR jobs\nSubmit a new job (it’s free)\n\tBrowse latest jobs (also free)\n\nContact us\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n\t\tWelcome!
     \t\t\t\r\nfunction init() {\r\nvar vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');\r\nfor (var i=0; i<vidDefer.length; i++) {\r\nif(vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) 
     {\r\nvidDefer[i].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));\r\n} } }\r\nwindow.onload = i"
```

RSelenium results:

```
> substring(rSelResults, 1, 500)
[1] "R news and tutorials contributed by (750) R bloggers\nHome\nAbout\nRSS\nadd your blog!\nLearn R\nR jobs\n�\n�\n�\nContact us\nWELCOME!\nHere you will find daily news and tutorials about R, 
     contributed by over 750 bloggers.\nThere are many ways to follow us -\nBy e-mail:\nOn Facebook:\nIf you are an R blogger yourself you are invited to add your own R content feed to this site (Non-English 
     R bloggers should add themselves- here)\nJOBS FOR R-USERS\nData/GIS Analyst for Ecoscape Environmental Consultants @ Kelowna, "
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [webdriver](https://github.com/rstudio/webdriver), which is a PhantomJS implementation, would do a better job (can't test against RSelenium at the moment):

```
library("webdriver")
library("rvest")

pjs <- run_phantomjs()
ses <- Session$new(port = pjs$port)
url <- 'https://www.r-bloggers.com'
ses$go(url)

res <- ses$getSource() %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_node('body') %>%
  html_text()

substring(res, 1, 500)
#> [1] "\n\n\n\t\t    \t    \t\n        \n        R news and tutorials contributed by (750) R bloggers         \n    Home\nAbout\nRSS\nadd your blog!\nLearn R\nR jobs\nSubmit a new job (it’s free)\n\tBrowse latest jobs (also free)\n\nContact us\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n\t\tWelcome!\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\nHere you will find daily news and tutorials about R, contributed by over 750 bloggers. \n\nThere are many ways to follow us - \nBy e-mail:\n\n\n<img src=\"https://feeds.feedburner.com/~fc/RBloggers?bg=99CCFF&amp;fg=444444&amp;anim=0\" height=\"26\" width=\"88\" sty"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It is an improvement indeed. However, there is still JavaScript Code in `res`, so i would upvote but not yet accept if that is ok,...

Comment: that's fine. And I would be happy to see a solution better than my own here. But out of interest, where do you see JS code in res? I can see a few HTML chunks but no JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex to clean up your data,

```
url <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com"

res <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('body') %>%
  html_text()

library(stringr)

# clean up text data
res %>%
  str_replace_all(pattern = "\n", replacement = " ") %>%
  str_replace_all(pattern = "[\\^]", replacement = " ") %>%
  str_replace_all(pattern = "\"", replacement = " ") %>%
  str_replace_all(pattern = "\\s+", replacement = " ") %>%
  str_trim(side = "both")
```