# Scrape a website that has javascript in R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

Hi there I am trying to scrape a few tables from this website.  https://money.tmx.com/en/quote/DOO/options

I have tried both an xpath and css. It seems that the java script is causing an issue. Here are my attempts

CSS:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
ticker = "DOO"
url = sprintf('https://money.tmx.com/en/quote/%s/options', ticker)
page = read_html(url) %>%html_nodes(css =  "div.options-table-wrap:nth-child(5)")
```

XPATH:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
ticker = "DOO"
url = sprintf('https://money.tmx.com/en/quote/%s/options', ticker)
page = read_html(url) %>%html_nodes(xpath =  "//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]")
```

Neither of these return anything. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using `RSelenium` or `webdriver` package, which loads javascripts. On the difference between `rvest` and the two mentioned packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370389/what-is-the-difference-between-rvesthtml-text-and-rseleniumgetpagesource

Comment: Rselenium is so slow tho IIRC  (lets say i wanted to pull 100 tickers instead of 1)

Comment: It is dynamically pulled from one of the requests you can find in network tab beginning with `https://app.quotemedia.com/datatool/getOptionQuotes.json` - it comes with a copyright warning,

Comment: okay i will give that a shot thanks @QHarr